# Typescript get object value from key

Tags: typescript

How to get the property using the index of the key of an object in typescript?

Despite the error on TypeScript, the code works correctly.

My code

```
const payments = {
  KEY1: {prop1: "prop1"},
  KEY2: {prop1: "prop1"}
}
```

When I try to access by key value I got the error

```
const index = 0

const key = Object.keys(payments)[index]
const payment = payments[key] // ERROR HERE
```

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.ts(7053)

`payments` is of type *object*

Comment: Did you try to type it ? `const payments: { [key: string]: {prop1: string} } = {}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this

```
const key = Object.keys(payments)[index] as keyof typeof payments;
```

When you don't explicitly declare type for `payments`, typescript inferred as specific keys(`KEY1` and `KEY2`)

and `Object.keys()` returns type as string that leads to error.

The above line I modified will tell typescript that `key` will be keys of payments and not string.

You can read more about this here [Creating Types from Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/types-from-types.html)